# How to stop ul list execution in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Please go through this sample code.

```
 <ul class="outer_most_ul">
 <li>first_child</li>
 <li>second_child</li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="outer_most_ul">
 <li>third_child</li>
 <li>fourth_child</li>
</ul>
```

I want to get all the childs of first ul.
  So, I use cssSelector but then I got all the elements of first and second  ul. How do I stop execution after getting all the elements of first ul.

```
List <WebElement> list_of_columns=wdriver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul[class='outer_most_ul'] li"));
for(WebElement columns : list_of_columns)
{
    System.out.println(wdriver.findElement(columns.getText().toString());
}
```

Using this code I got below output:-

```
first_child
second_child
third_child
fourth_child
```

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried, and what the result was... any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the first `ul` using `findElement` (note it will give you single element)

```
WebElement first = wdriver.findElement(By.className("outer_most_ul"));
```

And use it to find all the `li` childs

```
List <WebElement> list_of_columns = first.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
```

Comment: but both the ul tag have same classname thats the problem.So I get all the li tags from both the ul tags. but i want elements of first ul tag only

Comment: @GouravShivalkar `findElement` will give you the first element it finds (only one)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it just single `cssSelector` `query` as like below :-

```
List <WebElement> list_of_columns = wdriver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.outer_most_ul:nth-of-type(1) > li"));

for(WebElement columns : list_of_columns) {
        System.out.println(columns.getText().toString());
}
```

**Output** :-

```
first_child
second_child
```

**Note** :- If you would like to get all the childs of second `ul` then just change `:nth-of-type(1)` to `:nth-of-type(2)`..Means just change the `index`

Hope it will help you..:)